# what method do I call if I want to get the parent key if a certain type of child exist?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my Firebase data structure

```
2016-10-24 Monday" : {
"types" : {
  "LUNCH" : {
    "typeA" : "2",
    "typeB" : "1",
    "typeC" : "1"
  },
  "DINNER" : {
    "typeA" : "1",
    "typeB" : "2",
    "typeC" : "3"
  }
}"2016-10-26 Wednesday " : {
"types" : {
  "LUNCH" : {
    "typeA" : "0",
    "typeB" : "2",
    "typeC" : "3"
  },
  "DINNER" : {
    "typeA" : "2",
    "typeB" : "2"}
"2016-10-27 Thursday " : {
"types" : {
  "DINNER" : {
    "typeA" : "2",
    "typeB" : "2"
  }
```

and what I am trying to do now is :

If there is child("LUNCH") under date, I want to get which date are they
 (in this case are 2016-10-24 Monday and 2016-10-26 Wednesday)

I've read the firebase library and still have no idea what method I should call

please kindly help me out here, much appreciate !!

Comment: how you will get date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the snapshot for a given date, you can check if a child exists by calling [`FIRDataSnapshot.hasChild()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#-haschild).

```
refHandle = dateRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  if snapshot.hasChild("LUNCH") {
    println("\(snapshot.key)")
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid nesting your data structure too deep, Change your Data Structure to this:-

```
 Dates:{
    date1 : {
      LUNCH : true,
      DINNER : true
        },
    date2 : {
       DINNER : true
        }
      },
   LUNCH : {
     date1 : {
          "typeA" : "2",
          "typeB" : "1",
          "typeC" : "1"
        },
     date2 : {
           "typeA" : "0",
           "typeB" : "2",
           "typeC" : "3"
       }    
      },
   DINNER :{
     date1 : { 
               "typeA" : "1",
               "typeB" : "2",
               "typeC" : "3"}
      }
```

To get the **key** :-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Dates").queryOrdered(byChild : "Lunch").queryEqual(toValue: true).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in 

print(snap)
if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

    for each in snapDict{

        print(each.key)

   }
 }
})
```

Comment: hi Dravidian. Thanks for helping!!